# Instead of using switch statements how can I store a huge amount of words and pull from this "storage"?

Tags: ios, database

I am working on an iOS app that generates a random word every time a button is pressed. I currently generate the random words by using a switch statement with about 1000 cases. Is there a way to enter these words into some sort of dictionary or small database of some sort so I can just pull random words from there rather than having so many switch statements ? If yes, how should I go about doing this ?

Snippet of the switch statement

```
-(IBAction)randomWord {
int text = rand() % 1001;
switch (text) {



    case 0:
        theWord.text = @"Apple";
        break;
    case 1:
        theWord.text = @"Artichoke";
        break;
    case 2:
        theWord.text = @"Asparagus";
        break;

    case 3:
        theWord.text = @"Avocado";
        break;

    case 4:
        theWord.text = @"Bamboo";
        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the words in an array, and pass the random number to objectAtIndex:

Answer (score 1):

Put all of the words in a plist (as an array). Put the plist file in the Resources section of your app.

Then you can load the array from the plist when the app starts up. Then access a word from the array using a random index.